# Javascript IIFE helper functions - please help me understand how this works

Tags: javascript, module, destructuring, iife

```
String.prototype.capitalize =
     String.prototype.capitalize ||
  function() {
    return this[0].toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
  };

const Util = (function() {
  function textCase(str, tCase) {
    if (tCase) {
      return setCase(str, tCase);
    } else {
      return getCase(str);
    }

    function setCase(str, tCase) {
      switch (tCase) {
        case "uppercase":
          return str.toUpperCase();
        case "lowercase":
          return str.toLowerCase();
        case "capitalized":
          return str.capitalize();
        default:
            return str;
        }
    }

    function getCase(str) {
      if (str === str.toUpperCase()) {
        return "uppercase";
      }
      if (str === str.toLowerCase()) {
        return "lowercase";
      }
         if (str === str.capitalize()) {
        return "capitalized";
      }
      return "normal";
    }
  }

  return {
    textCase
  };
})();

function myReplace(str, before, after) {
  const { textCase } = Util;
  const regex = new RegExp(before, "gi");
  const replacingStr = textCase(after, textCase(before));

  return str.replace(regex, replacingStr);
}

myReplace("I think we should look up there", "up", "Down");
// "I think we should look down there"
```

I'm a novice coder who's tearing my hair out trying to understand the mechanics of this code.
It may be good code or bad code, but that's not the point. It's not my code.
I understand many of the individual blocks of code (e.g. creating a string method, creating a regex, destructuring assignment etc) but I'd massively appreciate it if someone could tell me, line by line, what exactly happens when the myReplace function executes with the given inputs.
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; that function uses a single method from the object returned by the IIFE. I don't think your question is about"myReplace" itself, rather about what value is stored in Util?

Comment: I'm asking if someone can show me what actually happens when you call the myReplace function? Specifically, when the str.replace method calls textCase (via replacingStr). As I understand it, first you call on the textCase function, passing after and textCase(before) as the two arguments. Presumably tCase returns falsy as it's not yet defined? So then getCase is invoked? A step-by-step explanation would really help me!

Comment: `textCase(before)` is called before `textCase(after, ...)` because it's a parameter to the "outer" `textCase`. In that first call, `tCase` is undefined, so yes, it calls `getCase`. Then `textCase(after, (results of first call))` is called, which would call `setCase` if the conditions are met. It's unclear what the confusion is--maybe you should put in some `console.logs` or step through it in the debugger? There's nothing too weird about any of it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have another look. I'm a novice coder, which is why stuff like this confuses me. I have very little experience of IIFEs and suchlike.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the purpose of return { textCase } please?

Comment: It returns an object with a single property named `textCase` with the value of `textCase` (the function). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Thank you for your help!